# How to evaluate $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x+x^2+x^3......+x^n} ; n> 1$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have found like ;

1.$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x+x^2} = \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}$

2.$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x+x^2+x^3} = \frac{\pi}{4}$

3.$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4} = \frac{\pi}{5} \cdot \sqrt{2-\frac{2}{\sqrt5}}$

4.$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5} = \frac{2\pi}{6\sqrt3}$

5.$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7} = \frac{2\pi}{8\sqrt3}$

In that way i'm trying to find $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x+x^2+x^3......+x^n} ; n> 1;$ But get stuck , can anyone help me by showing the process how to evaluate it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note  that $\sum_{0 \le k \le n} x^k = \frac{1 - x^{n +1}}{1 - x}$. The numerator of this can be factored into linear (complex) factors, partial fractions should take care of your general integral.

Comment: sorry, i can't evaluate it . help me in this regard.

Comment: $@$Crevious If you integrate $\dfrac{(z-1)\log(z)}{z^{n+1}-1}$ around a keyhole contour and use residue calculus then you get that the value of your integral is $\dfrac{\pi}{(n+1)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n+1}\right)}$.

Comment: It's interesting that the formula is even valid for complex values of $n+1$, while during the derivation you explicitly assume $n$ being an integer and it does not seem to work in a straightforward manner when $n$ is complex valued.