# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

> How to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5} dx$$

---

My Attempt:

$$I =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5} dx$$

$$I =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-x)}{(1 - x^6)} dx$$

Substituting $t = \frac{1}{x}$

$$I =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-\frac{1}{x})}{(1 - \frac{1}{x^6})} \cdot \frac{1}{x^2} dx$$

$$I =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-{x})(1 + x + x^2)}{(1-x^6 )} dx$$

This does not seem to work.

Comment: $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5=(x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1)(x^2 - x + 1)$, that you can find by noticing that $x^6-1=(x^3-1)(x^3+1)$. Then's it's standard partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That would be a lot of work. I am pretty sure there is a simpler way.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore It shows here that your post has been deleted and no longer viewable.

Comment: @Whyareyoureadingmyname reload the page

Comment: You might be interested to learn about a more general formula for this type of problem, to be found (and explained) at [1]: 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x+x^2+x^3…+x^n} = \dfrac{\pi}{(n+1)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n+1}\right)}
$$


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3624930/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that by replacing $x\to \frac{1}{x}$ $$I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-x}{1-x^6}dx=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(1-x)x^3}{1-x^6}dx$$Adding  $$2I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(1-x)(1+x^3)}{1-x^6}= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-x}{1-x^3}=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$$ which should be easy..

Comment: And, if it is not easy, try the same $1/x$ trick again on $$\int\frac{1-x}{(1-x^3)}\;dx$$

Comment: @GEdgar But actually that results in the same thing